# How to get Full row from repeater control in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, repeater

I am using repeater control to create a table with few rows and columns. On Repeater_ItemCommand I want to select clicked row in the code behind and store it in the session. How do I do this ?

When I click the row, my e.Item.DataItem is coming NULL. I am using <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FILE_NAME")%> to bind my values in asp.net

I cant use LINQ.

Thanks
Ved

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code for the repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
        onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <ul>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteComment" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="DeleteComment" CommandArgument=<%#Eval("myId") %>></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName")%>'></asp:Label>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the code for the code behind

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public class myObject
        {
            public string FileName { get; set; }
            public int myId { get; set; }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<myObject> myList = new List<myObject>();
            myList.Add(new myObject {myId = 1, FileName = "one" });
            myList.Add(new myObject { myId = 2, FileName = "two" });
            myList.Add(new myObject { myId = 3, FileName = "three" });

            Repeater1.DataSource = myList;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            Label item = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("label1");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Label item = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("label1"); worked for me. It saved my lot of time. @atbebtg Thanks for answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

From what i know about Repeater, it is not supposed to be used like that. Why not just use GridView and TemplateField?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"                 
            DataKeyNames="KeyColumnName"   
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">  
            <Columns>  
                <asp:TemplateField>
                     ...Same template as in repater...
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>  
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I would love to but its out of my hand..I have to use repeater

Comment: @Ivan: Why do you say repeaters "not supposed to be used that way"?

Comment: @Shai Cohen: From what i've read, its used for data rendering but not data manipulation. MSDN seems to agree : "The Repeater control has no built-in selection capabilities or editing support".(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @IvanKoshelew: From my experience, all the other "rich" controls just add extended functionality to the basic repeater (ie: paging, edit rows, sorting, etc.). BUT, you still need to implement these manually. Usually, any control that "does it all for you" also does too much for you, costing you overhead for features you are not necessarily using. I am not saying these controls are not useful, but their usefulness comes at a price. If you are doing RAD, I can see why you want to roll it out as fast as possible, but if you are looking for long-term efficient, use the repeater. IMHO.

Comment: @IvanKoshelew: This has become a discussion, so if you would like to discuss some more, let's join a chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Buttons'/LinkButtons'/etc. CommandArgument field.

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="someRepeater" OnItemCommand="someRepeater_ItemCommand" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr><th>
                File Name Header
            </th></tr>                                    
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr><td>
                <asp:LinkButton Text="File Name Item" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FILE_NAME")%>' Style="display: block" runat="server" />
            </td></tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

In code behind:

```
protected void someRepeater_ItemCommand(object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Session["FILE_NAME"] = e.CommandArgument; //Here you have your FILE_NAME
}
```

This is, of course, some example code.

Comment: I want to select the entire row, I am not using server controls. Displaying text inside TD.

Comment: as far as i know `Repeater.ItemCommand` event _Occurs when a **button** is clicked in the Repeater control._ You can have a `LinkButton` with CSS style `display:block` inside each `<td>` with command argument and Text property.